# jQuery checked input returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please tell me why the console doesn't see the checked value of the input tag?

[image]

Comment: Use attr instead of prop

Comment: Prop of check current state not the attribute value

Comment: There is a really good explanation of this topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5835/ - works fine here - I think this is a problem in your code.

Comment: Do you have multiple input's with that same id?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort instead of pictures of code